# Wordpress - subdomain to root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've been building a wordpress site on a subdomain while having my old website in the root directory. Now I have finished the site and would like to move it into the root. Is there a way how to 'redirect' my site so I don't need to move all the files and databases from the subdomain? The address should appear as www.myweb.com, though.

I have these folders in my FTP:
public_html, _sub, tmp

The subdomain is currently located at _sub/wc/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This codex article should explain the process, I've used it successfully myself several times: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Comment: I've checked this, but how do I point it to the wp-blog-header.php, which is on subdomain? Because the _sub folder isn't located in public_html on my FTP and writing 'http://sub.example.com/wp-blog-header.php' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to wordpress you can leave your files where they are and put the following into your wp-config file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/new/');                   
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com/new/');
```

Or you can:

> In the box for WordPress address (URL): change the address to the new
> location of your main WordPress core files. Example:
> http://example.com/wordpress
>
> In the box for Site address (URL): change
> the address to the root directory's URL. Example: http://example.com

Take a look at moving wordpress: [Moving_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and editing the wp-config [Editing_wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) as well as [Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Wordpress gives a lot of information about moving domains etc, and it is well worth reading their documentation on the matter.

You may want to remove your old website files (it is good to have a back up of the old version anyway) so that they do not conflict (esp if they are WordPress).